# Python TypeError - : 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, typeerror

This is my code.

```
n1, n2 = (int(input("Enter number: ")) for _ in range(2))
print("Select Your Choice: ")
print(" 1: Addition",
       "2: Substraction",
       "3: Multiplication",
       "4: Division")
choice = int(input())

switcher = {
        1: "Addition",
        2: "Substraction",
        3: "Multiplication",
        4: "Division",
    }
def addition(n1,n2):
    n1 += n2
    return n1

def substraction(n1,n2):
    n1 -= n2
    return n1

def multiplication(n1,n2):
    n1 *= n2
    return n1

def division(n1,n2):
    n1 /= n2
    return n1

def calculator(choice,n1,n2):
    return switcher.get(choice,"Invalid")(n1,n2)

print(calculator(choice,n1,n2))
```

I got below error.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   
> simple calculator with dictionary.py", line 36, in <module>
> print(calculator(choice,n1,n2))   
> simple calculator with dictionary.py", line 34, in calculator

> > return switcher.get(choice,"Invalid")(n1,n2) 
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Can anyone solve this error?

Comment: Please reformat the code, its hardly readable.

Comment: Could you make it work?

Answer (score 3):

The values in `switcher` have to be the functions you defined, not strings.

```
switcher = {
    1: addition,
    2: substraction,
    3: multiplication,
    4: division,
}
```

Put this initialization of `switcher` after the definition of your functions.

You'll still get the "string not callable" error for invalid inputs, because

```
"Invalid"(n1, n2)
```

is not a valid function call. Adjust `calculator` to do something else for invalid inputs.